# Как вставить символ перед последним </div> с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!

Есть такая строка:

```
$string = "<body><div></div><div></div><tr><td></td></tr></body>";
```

Как с помощью preg_replace и регулярных выражений вставить символ перед последним `</div>`?

 участок `<tr><td></td></tr>` может быть любым, поэтому брут-форс такого вида не подходит:

```
$string = "<body><div></div><div></div></body>";
function insertInto($what, $object){
    $pattern = '/\<\/div\>\<\/body\>$/i';
    $replacement = $what.'${0}';
    $newString = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $object);
    return $newString;
}
$string = insertInto('X', $string);
print $string; //Результат: <body><div></div><div>X</div></body>
```

Comment: я думаю сперва стоить разобраться с вашим предыдущем вопросом, а потом уже разберемся с этим.

Comment: привет! с предыдущим же уже разобрались...

Comment: а... сори, не поставил галочку. за предыдущий спс!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Как с помощью preg_replace и регулярных выражений вставить символ перед последним `</div>`?*

Составить шаблон на поиск всех символов, которые заканчиваются тегом `</div>` и подставить в строку замены вместе с вашим символом:

```
$str = '<body><div></div><div></div><tr><td></td></tr></body>';

echo preg_replace('~<div[^>]*>.+(?=</div>)~s', '$0СИМВОЛ', $str);
```

---

UPD: Подправил шаблон.
Результат:

```
<body><div></div><div>СИМВОЛ</div><tr><td></td></tr></body>
```

Comment: __О г о н ь !__

Comment: А можешь подсказать, почему вместо `/` ты используешь `~`?

Comment: А... Всё, понял. При `/` нужно `<>...` экранировать

Comment: @O.O использую знак тильда `~` потому, что  он удобнее выглядит, а так же потому, что если в шаблоне встречаются слеши, то их не нужно экранировать.

Comment: Я, малость, сократил ;-) `'~^.+(?=</div>)~i'`

Comment: C п а с и б о !

Answer (score 2):

Функция допускает лишь строчный поиск и замену не по регулярным шаблонам:

```
$string = '<body><div></div><div></div><tr><td></td></tr></body>';

echo str_replace_end('</div>', 'X', $string);

function str_replace_end($search, $replace, $subject)
{
    $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);

    if($pos !== false) {
        $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace . $search, $pos, strlen($search));
    }

    return $subject;
}
```

На выходе получаем:

```
<body><div></div><div>X</div><tr><td></td></tr></body>
```

Comment: Ну вот уже вторая функция ;)

Comment: @Manitikyl, согласеен))

Comment: @Manitikyl, осталось лишь сделать по регулярным выражениям)

Comment: У меня даже идей нет как это на регулярках реализовать, поэтому пусть кто-то другой делает))

Comment: @Manitikyl, там даже проще, сейчас покажу

Comment: Воу воу воу, не бери грех на душу... тут без регулярок все норм)

Comment: @Manitikyl, ладно :D

Comment: чет старею, уже забыл, что `.*</div>` - возьмет последний.

Comment: @Manitikyl, сколько тебе?

Comment: Let'ssayPie, 26 :>

Comment: @Manitikyl, дядя :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "<body><div></div><div></div><tr><td></td></tr></body>";
$element = '</div>';

$pos = strripos($string, $element);
if ($pos !== FALSE) {
    $string = substr_replace($string, 'X', $pos, 0);
}
echo $string;
```